# Generating a new access token for PartnerCenter

Tags: azure, powershell

About 3 months ago I created an token for login to Microsoft PartnerCenter, this token has now expired and i need to create a new one but I lost the code I used and when doing as it says in the documentation it doesnt work.

Im trying to follow Example 1 in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/partnercenter/new-partneraccesstoken?view=partnercenterps-3.0

But what confuses me is what i should put in the credentials object? Is it the AppID and the App Secret or is it something else?

```
$TenantID = "MyTenant" #  Tenant
$ApplicationID = "MyAppID" # Application in Tenant "Partner Center"
$ApplictionSecret = "MyAPPSecreat" 

$credential = New-Object PSCredential ($ApplicationID, (ConvertTo-SecureString $ApplictionSecret -AsPlainText -Force))
$token = New-PartnerAccessToken -ApplicationId $ApplicationID -Scopes 'https://api.partnercenter.microsoft.com/user_impersonation' -ServicePrincipal -Credential $credential -Tenant $TenantID -UseAuthorizationCode
```

What happens when i run this is that i end up in a never ending loop where a my webbrowser opens and ask me to login and when i login it just creates a new tab and in the powershell window i get a warning and the port number increases for each time i do it.

```
WARNING: Port 8400 is taken with exception 'Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted'; trying to connect to the next port.
WARNING: Port 8401 is taken with exception 'Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted'; trying to connect to the next port.
WARNING: Port 8402 is taken with exception 'Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted'; trying to connect to the next port.
WARNING: Port 8403 is taken with exception 'Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted'; trying to connect to the next port.
WARNING: Attempting to launch a browser for authorization code login.
WARNING: We have launched a browser for you to login. For the old experience with device code flow, please run 'New-PartnerAccessToken -UseDeviceAuthentication'.
WARNING: Port 8400 is taken with exception 'Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted'; trying to connect to the next port.
WARNING: Port 8401 is taken with exception 'Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted'; trying to connect to the next port.
WARNING: Port 8402 is taken with exception 'Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted'; trying to connect to the next port.
WARNING: Port 8403 is taken with exception 'Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted'; trying to connect to the next port.
WARNING: Port 8404 is taken with exception 'Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted'; trying to connect to the next port.
WARNING: Attempting to launch a browser for authorization code login.
WARNING: We have launched a browser for you to login. For the old experience with device code flow, please run 'New-PartnerAccessToken -UseDeviceAuthentication'.
WARNING: Port 8400 is taken with exception 'Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted'; trying to connect to the next port.
WARNING: Port 8401 is taken with exception 'Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted'; trying to connect to the next port.
WARNING: Port 8402 is taken with exception 'Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted'; trying to connect to the next port.
WARNING: Port 8403 is taken with exception 'Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted'; trying to connect to the next port.
WARNING: Attempting to launch a browser for authorization code login.
WARNING: We have launched a browser for you to login. For the old experience with device code flow, please run 'New-PartnerAccessToken -UseDeviceAuthentication'.
```

And no, there is nothing blocking/listening on that port before i run the command. I tried restart the computer and used netstat to verify that there is nothing listening on the port.

Also note that im using the same application as i did 3 months ago when i managed to get it working, so i doubt its a configuration error on that side. Its probably something im going wrong in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution to this problem was fairly easy.

I just had to change the default browser to Internet Explorer (from Chrome) and then it worked. Seems to be some kind of bug.